# How to postpone the initialization of the swiper/angular until the slide elements are loaded

Tags: angular, swiper.js

How to postpone the initialization of the swiper/angular until the slide elements are loaded.
The thing is that if the elements are static, the data-swiper-autoplay="500" works correctly, but if you output in the loop, then autoplay is taken prescribed in the tag swiper

https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-angular-forked-c1e8ww?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found! It should have been done this way:

```
[attr.data-swiper-autoplay]="item.timeout"
```